# What do the different colours of the comment flag mean?

Tags: support, flagging, comments

Why do the comment flags have different colours in the screenshot below? what do they mean/indicate? and why do they change colours when the page is reloaded?

The answer is not obvious to me, because it can't be comment length (short comments - like red and yellow arrow - have the differing colours) and it can't be because some are upvoted and others are not (green and yellow arrows have differing colours).

Maybe it's  about time elapsed since flag was raised? Not sure.

**It's not really a problem**, but some clarity would be nice.

Screenshot taken from [this](https://superuser.com/questions/527401/troubleshoot-high-cpu-usage-by-the-system-process?rq=1) question immediately after flagging and then after reloading the page -
[image: Differently coloured comment flags]   -------->  [image: Uniformly coloured comment flags]

Answer (score 3):

1. Bright red means that you flagged the corresponding comment
2. Dark red means that others have flagged the corresponding comment
3. Gray means that nobody have flagged the corresponding comment